# Custom Shopify "Close Preview" button

Tags: javascript, shopify, liquid

I'm wondering if there is a way to create a custom "Close Preview" button as seen when previewing a theme (image example below):

[image: Close Preview Button demo]

I tried looking around the Liquid documentation but can't seem to find anything

Comment: This is injected Shopify's side, you cannot modify it.

Comment: @AliceGirard, I'm not looking to modify it, I'm looking to replicate it